# iOS :: error is nil if not able to download file with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsurlsession

I am downloading files in the app using `NSURLSession` and `NSURLSessionTask`. If file is present on the server then it works fine. If file is not available then it writes the data into the file and don't download it.
For example :: if file is not available the it writes

> Access is denied

in the file and completes the task without any error. In this case error comes as nil.

But i want to show alert box to the user saying file is not available.

Below is the code...

```
task1 = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[S3_SERVER_URL stringByAppendingString:propFile]] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            propfilePath = [[Util getInAppTempPath] stringByAppendingString:propFile];
            NSLog(@"DestPath : %@", propfilePath);
            [receivedData appendData:data];
            NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %lu bytes of data",(unsigned long)[data length]);
            //[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            [data writeToFile:propfilePath atomically:YES];

            //NSLog(@"iOSDBVersion: %@", [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"iOSDBVersion"]);
            //NSLog(@"ttodDBVersion: %@", [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"ttodDBVersion"]);
            if(error == nil){
                [Util getDataFromPlistFile];
                [Util isAppRunBefore];
                [self downloadDatabase];

            } else {
                [self alertNoPlist];
            }

        }];
        [task1 resume];
```

It never goes into the else block.

I tired to put this in `try catch block` then also no luck.

How can I handle these kind of errors in iOS?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in that completion block to see what is set?  I suspect you say "It never goes into the else block" because you aren't seeing an alert; however I don't believe that is good enough proof (i.e. the alertview might not be showing as the thread is not the main thread).

Comment: yes i kept breakpoint at the start itself...it gives error is nil, response some hex value, data as 250 bytes...

Comment: Check status code of response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the server is returning a response code such as 401 (Unauthorized), along with a body such as "Access is denied." This is a not an error in the `NSURLSession` sense. This is a completely legitimate response, so you wouldn't expect anything in `error`.

Instead, you need to check the response's `statusCode` value. This should be between 200-299 for success. As I said, you probably are getting 401.

Note that you're passed an `NSURLResponse`. You will likely need to cast this to `NSHTTPURLResponse` in order to access its `statusCode`.

Answer (score 1):

Used below code to get the httpresponse status code.

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
            NSLog(@"response status code: %ld", (long)[httpResponse statusCode]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `dataTaskWithURL:` for downloading the image. For download tasks you should use `downloadTaskWithURL:`.

```
[[session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[S3_SERVER_URL stringByAppendingString:propFile]] completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        // Show error
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:location toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:propfilePath] error:nil];
    }
}] resume];
```

For more details refer :

1. [NSURLSessionDownloadTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadTask_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLSessionDownloadTask)
2. [NSURLSessionDataTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataTask_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLSessionDataTask)